# Требуется в конце каждой седьмой строки вставить строку ".---"

Tags: строки, notepad++

Есть у меня текстовый файл (более 16000 строк)

```
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################

и т.д. (вместо решёток стоят разные символы)
```

Требуется в конце каждой седьмой строки (со словом SPLIT) добавить ".---" (пропустив первую строку в файле и добавляя в конце её тоже ".---"), чтобы было так:

```
##################.---
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################.---
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################.---
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################.---
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################
##################SPLIT##################.---

и т.д.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать регуляркой, так:

Найти: `(.+SPLIT.+)$`

Заменить на: `$1.---`

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/r7j5TP/1
Скрин: http://prntscr.com/142y5gl

Удачи ;-)